# What does re.compile(r'[[]]') match?

Tags: python, regex

With Python's re module, why do the following act differently:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'[][]')
>>> r.findall(r'[]')
['[', ']']
>>> r = re.compile(r'[[]]')
>>> r.findall(r'[]')
['[]']
>>> r.findall(r'][')
[]
```

Comment: I made a slight change to the example code (moving the string-to-match from s=".." to the findall argument, so it's a bit clearer), and pointed out [][] and [[]] produce different results. Also removed the python tag from the title as it's a bit redundant given the tag

Comment: That it's Python _is_ important information, though; regex flavors vary wildly on how they deal with square brackets in character classes. In Java, both of those regexes would result in PatternSyntaxExceptions.

Answer (score 16):

The regular expression "[[]]" matches the substring "[]". The first [ in the expression begins a character class, and the first ] ends it. There is only one character ([) in the class, and then it has to be followed by the second ]. So the expression is "any of the characters in "[", followed by a "]".

Answer (score 4):

Character classes begin with a **`[`** and end with the first **`]`**.

So the expression `[][]` is a character class with the characters `]` and `[` as character classes must not be empty:  **`[`**`][`**`]`**
And the expression `[[]]` is a character class with just `[` and the single character `]` after that: **`[`**`[`**`]`**`]`

Answer (score 0):

and r'[][]' forms a character class {'[',']'}, and match either '[' or ']'.

Comment: Nope, that defines two empty character classes, r'[a][b]' for example wont match a][b, it'll match a, then b

Comment: You’re right. r'[][]' form a character class containing ']' and '[' as character classes must not be empty.